# Retrieving auto-increment database value

Tags: php, mysql

I need to retrieve the auto increment value and store it in the session after the insert query is performed.

My table name is out where I have 4 fields id(primary key and auto increment), name, phone, email.

```
$query = mysql_query($con, "insert into out(name, phone, email) values ('$name', '$phone', '$email')");                                                                            
$id = mysql_insert_id($con);                                                                               
while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{ 
 $id= $rowval['id']; 
 }
if($query)
{ 
  $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
}
```

Comment: what you have done code for this??

Comment: after insertion of record into the database get the last insertion id from datbase and keep it in session...

Comment: so insertion is done??

Comment: Everything related to this, should update in question, don't comment this.

Comment: use $id = mysql_insert_id(); to get last inserted id it will come after that keep this id in session..

Comment: But it is not stored in session.

Comment: @Sona yes insertion is done

Comment: remove `while` remove your code will work. Also don't use `mysql` its removed form latest version of PHP

Comment: Thank You Rishi but I'm using the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most universal way to get the last insert id it to simply select it.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$lastId = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  try this.
$sql = mysql_query($con, "INSERT INTO(col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3)";
$mysql->query($sql); 
$last_inserted_id=$mysql->insert_id; // returns last ID


//you can get last inserted id then set it in session.
```

Comment: He is in `mysql_*` mode for now

Comment: Which variable should I use to store in session?

Comment: $last_inserted_id add it in session.

Comment: $_SESSION["sess_id"]=$last_inserted_id;  for start session.

Comment: When I use this $mysql->query($sql); $last_inserted_id=$mysql->insert_id; the script is not running.

Comment: I have a script if query executed properly  echo '<script language="javascript">';
     echo 'window.location.href = "print.php";';
     echo 'alert("Done");';
     echo '</script>';

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = mysql_query($con, "insert into out(name, phone, email) values ('$name', '$phone', '$email')");                                                                            
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

> // Just Remove $con...

```
while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{ 
 $id= $rowval['id']; 
 }
if($query)
{ 
  $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
}
```